# Multiple rows, with multiple values, how to get higher value for same row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, numbers

I'm having data contained in my SQL database,
its about students and their cards which they are using to log in to system,
sometimes students lose their card and they get another one, but same row which contains informations about student card was not updated,
in fact new row was added, so we are getting situation:

There is one student with 2 cards and how could I determine which one is newer because there is no colum about 'DateCreated' or smth...

I also find out if I see higher CardId for same student,
that means that 'higher' number is currently active card for user, so how could I remove old Id's..

Here is the photo:
[image]

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  This is critical to know.

Comment: Please, post sample data as formatted text instead of as pictures. (I can't read that picture's small text.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its microsoft sql server

Comment: Yes, you already said this, I gave you a query below.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
DELETE a
FROM   <your table name> a 
WHERE  EXISTS 
              (SELECT 1 
              FROM   <your table name> b 
              WHERE  b.StudentId = a.StudentId 
              AND    b.CardId > a.CardId)
```

This query will delete all student records which exists other records that have same StudentId and value of CardId bigger than CardId of deleted record.

Comment: Would this work across all databases?  We don't know the database being used.

Comment: Probably portable, core ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen its Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: @TrungDuong Can you please explain it more detailed?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it's still unclear to you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do a delete self join, using a CTE to identify the records which should be deleted.  A record should be deleted if a) it appears as a pair for a given `StudentID`, and b) it is the minimum `CardID` for that `StudentID`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT StudentID, MIN(CardID) AS CardID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1      -- only do a delete if a pair be present
)
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND
       t1.CardID    = t2.CardID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the higher card id is the valid one then you can implement the below trigger on your table which will delete the old records automatically when you insert a row into the table.

```
Create Trigger delete_old_record
On <Your_Table_Name>
After Insert
AS

delete from <Your_Table_Name> where [Student ID]=(select [Student ID] from Inserted )
and [Card_ID]<(select [Card_ID] from Inserted)

Go
```